# 3D navigation using a Space Pilot Pro

Tags: interface, 3d-view, 3d-mouse

I have a question about 3D Space Navigators within Blender. The model I'm currently using is the Space Pilot Pro, a logitec product by 3dconnexion. I am not able to pan the view with my SpacePilot Pro 3D mouse.

How do I get this device to pan the view?  For some reason it is locked by default.

Comment: Have you tried to tweak the 3D mouse settings, by pressing the "Menu" or "config" buttons ? (I can't tell you precisely which one, because I have the old spacePilot - not pro - from HP) BTW there is a menu displayed in 3D view when hitting some of these buttons. You may find something useful in there...

Comment: if you press the shift key the space mouse will pan left/right, up/down

Answer (score 3):

Using the default configuration you'll need to hold down <kbd>shift</kbd> while tweaking the knob for panning. Your Space Pilot Pro should have a <kbd>shift</kbd> built into it for easy access.

You can also adjust Blender's NDOF keymap to better suite your liking.

[image]